# Can a user control have a Master Page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I am creating a page that has several user controls (similar to WebParts). Each widget has a common UI section and Content section.

I implemented this using a ParentUserControl that has the common elements and a ChildUserControl that has the content. It works great so far.

I am curious to know if I should have used a single control that has a MasterPage with common UI elements and include this MasterPage across all other children controls? (ofcourse assuming MasterPage can be used within a UC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately MasterPages are designed to work with the `Page` type.  The `Page` type is designed to use its `OnPreInit` method to initialize and set up the MasterPage.  For this and several other reasons MasterPages cannot be used with UserControls.

What you have set up now sounds pretty good - is there a reason you want to change it?

Comment: So far what I have - the page loads parent controls that load child controls and everything happens dynamically. With dynamic loading of controls come other issues related to ViewState etc. A cleaner approach would be to load controls that dont have nested controls. I thought MP is a good fit

Comment: I agree - it would be really nice to be able to use MPs with UserControls but we will have to wait until Microsoft makes that happen :)